# How can I test whether a plot has a fixed aspect ratio in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, aspect-ratio

I wonder if there is a way to ask R whether a plot has or has not a fixed aspect ratio. Here are two example plots:

```
library (ggplot2)

plot_a <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
          geom_point()+
          theme (aspect.ratio = 1)

plot_b <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
          geom_point()
```

Whereas `plot_a` has a fixed aspect ratio, `plot_b` has no fixed aspect ratio. I am in search of the following imaginary function:

```
is_fixed_ratio (plot_a) 
TRUE

is_fixed_ratio (plot_b)
FALSE
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have the following plots:

```
library (ggplot2)

plot_a <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
          geom_point()+
          theme (aspect.ratio = 1)

plot_b <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
          geom_point()

plot_c <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
          geom_point() +
          coord_equal()
```

The current accepted answer would treat these as follows:

```
is_fixed_ratio <- function(plot){
  purrr::map(plot, "aspect.ratio") %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    is.null() %>% 
    !.
}
```

```
> is_fixed_ratio(plot_a)
[1] TRUE
> is_fixed_ratio(plot_b)
[1] FALSE
> is_fixed_ratio(plot_c)
[1] FALSE
```

Whereas `plot_c` does have a fixed aspect ratio, just not specified through the theme.

To check for this, you can inspect the gtable of the plot:

```
is_fixed_ratio2 <- function(plot) {
  ggplotGrob(plot)$respect
}
```

```
> is_fixed_ratio2(plot_a)
[1] TRUE
> is_fixed_ratio2(plot_b)
[1] FALSE
> is_fixed_ratio2(plot_c)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is IMO a much better answer than the accepted one, and is probably less likely to change in future.

Comment: Just noticed this answer after having posted essentially [the same.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58738418/4975218)

Comment: Great to know that at least it was correct, but your explanation is more on point I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

Edited to check for any aspect ratio

```
> !is.null(plot_a$theme$aspect.ratio)
[1] TRUE
> !is.null(plot_b$theme$aspect.ratio)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Ok, this works fine if the `aspect.ratio` is exactly 1. However, if there is a fixed aspect ratio deviating from 1, `isTRUE(the_plot$theme$aspect.ratio == 1)` it would return FALSE, I suppose (and I just want to test *if* there is a fixed aspect ratio). I could try with a reasonably small value which would word in most cases, I suppose:

`isTRUE(the_plot$theme$aspect.ratio >= .0001)`

Comment: Testing if there is an aspect ratio is just as simple. Just need to check if that `aspect.ratio` list element exists.

Comment: This is the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A really nice way when dealing with such problems is to use `map`from the `purrr` package. With this, you do not have to search in the list manually:

```
is_fixed_ratio <- function(plot){
  purrr::map(plot, "aspect.ratio") %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    is.null() %>% 
    !.
}
is_fixed_ratio(plot_a)
is_fixed_ratio(plot_b)
```

Comment: This is a very nice option, indeed. I do like the idea of testing via a dedicated function due to the human-readability.

Answer (score 2):

The answers that query the theme are not reliable, because a plot can have a fixed aspect ratio simply because the coord makes it so, regardless of the theme settings. For example, any plots based on `geom_sf()` will have a fixed aspect ratio. The correct way to do this is to query the grob that ggplot generates.

```r
library(tidyverse)

p_var <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point()

p_fixed <- p_var + coord_fixed()


# correct approach: query the grob
is_fixed_ratio <- function(plot) {
  g <- ggplotGrob(plot)
  isTRUE(g$respect)
}

# should return false
is_fixed_ratio(p_var)
#> [1] FALSE

# should return true
is_fixed_ratio(p_fixed)
#> [1] TRUE
```

By contrast, if we try the incorrect approach, things don't work as expected.

```r
# incorrect approach: rely on a theme setting
is_fixed_ratio_wrong <- function(plot) {
  purrr::map(plot, "aspect.ratio") %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    is.null() %>% 
    !.
}

# should return false, and does so
is_fixed_ratio_wrong(p_var)
#> [1] FALSE

# should return true, but doesn't
is_fixed_ratio_wrong(p_fixed)
#> [1] FALSE
```

This works also for the example given in the question:

```r
plot_a <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)

plot_b <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()

is_fixed_ratio(plot_a)
#> [1] TRUE

is_fixed_ratio(plot_b)
#> [1] FALSE
```

One more example:

```r
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
p <- ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA))

is_fixed_ratio(p)
#> [1] TRUE

is_fixed_ratio_wrong(p)
#> [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about a function, but there is a 'quick and dirty' way to check this. if you expand the plots sub window, a plot without a fixed aspect ratio will stretch and expand, while a plot with a fixed ratio will stay the same width.

You can also specify the scale, width and height of a plot directly with ggsave, e.g.

```
ggsave("figure.png", plot = last_plot(),
   scale = 1, width = 20, height = 15, units = "cm",
   dpi = 300)
```

Could you maybe specify how you would want to check your plots?

Comment: I know :)
However, I need R to "know" whether a plot has a fixed `aspect.ratio`or not, because I want to implement the answer (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) in a larger function.